# RxJava 2, how do I place in my conditional here?

Tags: android, realm, retrofit, rx-java, rx-java2

Is it possible at all to replace this conditional:

```
if (_file.exists) {
  //rxjava post
}
else {
  //another type of post
}
```

A generic version of the post below:

```
service.setSolicitation("Berlin", getString(R.string.api_key))
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
// Read results in Android Main Thread (UI)
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
.subscribe(this::processError);
```

I really don't want to keep repeating myself nor to use that if loop in order to avoid a null pointer exception. Are there any fancy options involving rx java?

**Edit**

So I have two observables on my retrofit API interface.

```
@POST("solicitation/create ")
Observable<Solicitation> createSolicitation(@Query("X-Authorization") String apiKey, @Body Solicitation solicitation);
```

and

```
@Multipart
@POST("solicitation/create")
Observable<Solicitation> uploadFileMap(
        @Query("X-Authorization") String apiKey,
        @PartMap() Map<String, RequestBody> partMap,
        @Part MultipartBody.Part file);
```

Why do I have two observables for the same thing? Because I use one if a file exists and the other if a file doesn't exists.

Therefore I need to check with a conditional `if (_file.exists)`.

I wanna simplify it all instead of having to deal with multiple if statements.. (already have one to check if we're online, if not online add to queue). So I'm nesting ifs and it's horrible.

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are trying to avoid. The conditional does not appear related to the example RxJava call that you have shown. Can you perhaps clarify?

Comment: I'll update to try to make it a little clearer, give me a second.

Comment: @ScottW There, is that better or would you like me to add more details?

Comment: Thank you, it is much more clear now. Unfortunately, I am not aware of any fancy solution to this, other than abstracting the logic out into a separate function that you can call from those multiple places.

Comment: Aren't you looking for `Optional`?

Comment: Could you please elaborate Zhuiden? @EpicPandaForce

Answer (score 0):

Use an actual if-else, but just on the parts that differ:

```
Observable.defer(() -> 
    someCondition() 
    ? service.setSolicitation("Berlin", getString(R.string.api_key))
    : service.createSolicitation(....)
) 
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
// Read results in Android Main Thread (UI)
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
.subscribe(this::processError);
```